# Lion: Arrange Bug?

Tags: macos, finder, bug

I have arrange by kind turned on at all times, yet sometimes I see a strange bug:

[image: example of the bug]

As you can see, the arrange headers: "Folders", "PDF Documents" and "Documents" do not show up properly. They are shown just as folders. I cannot select them or move them.

Does anyone else have this bug? What can I do about this?

The bug persists, even after I did a clean install.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the window that comes up when you press Command+J in the Finder?

Comment: Can you also post a screen shot of what you get when you select one of those folders (Folders, Documents, PDF Documents)?

Comment: @CajanLuke, As said in the question, these folders cannot be selected.

Comment: @Matt Love momentarily everything is okay again (usually changing between two types of arranging, ei "kind" to "size", fixes the problem temporarily). I will try to capture cmd+J when it is bad again.

Comment: You may find list view works better for this sort of thing. (Personally I can't fathom why some people like column view as the default, but to each his own.)

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder to me column view is the fastest way of navigation. Using the arrow keys you can go really fast! And using list view with arrange doesn't allow me to navigate at all!

Comment: @romeovs I don't really want this to turn into a conversation on the (de)merits of each of the view styles, but you can use the command-arrows to navigate in list view.

Comment: If the problem persists, you may want to file a bug report with Apple https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: A year later and Lion's still doing this. Wow.

Answer (score 2):

I too have seen this bug.
This is an issue with Finder's styling of headers in column view (and maybe other views).

The list interface headers are not "interactive" per-say (meaning selectable and movable), however there is a bug with Finder's styling of the headers for arrange/sort by kind which when rendered incorrectly, makes the headers appear as a regular named folder in the list of files.

Closing all Finder windows and reopening them is not a proper solution, however it does reset the Finder "styling engine" (for lack of time to term it properly) so that it shows the header as a list interface header, and not a folder in the list of files and folder in column view.

I cannot reproduce the problem consistently, however, I often notice it when I have multiple finder windows open, and may even go so far as to tie in the blame with network folder listings in Finder.
I can't verify this but that's my environment a lot of the time.